# Getting junk value from file pointer?

Tags: c++

Below is my code what i am trying to do is storing in a array the characters from a particular file pointed by fptr, user is giving the position from where the character will be copied in a array but am getting junk value always.
Can anyone tell me why is this happening ?
any help will be appreciated.

```
void copy()
{
    int i,j,temp=0;
    FILE *fptr;
    count=0;

    cout<<"enter i"<<endl;
    cin>>i;

    cout<<"enter j"<<endl;
    cin>>j;

    i--;j--;

    fptr=fopen("filename","r");
    fseek(fptr,i,SEEK_SET);

    temp=j-i+1;
    char x;
    while(temp--)
    {
        x=getc(fptr);
        cout<<"x="<<x<<endl;
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and use appropriate tags.

Comment: fopen() returns NULL if file "filename" does not exist. You should check return-value of fopen()